# Problem from "Differential topology" by Guillemin

Tags: differential-topology

I am strugling one of the problems of "Differential Topology" by Guillemin: 
Suppose that $Z$ is an $l$-dimensional submanifold of $X$ and that $z\in Z$. Show that there exsists a local coordinate system $\left \{ x_{1},...,x_{k} \right \}$ defined in a neighbourhood  $U$ of $z$ such that $Z \cap U$ is defined by the equations $x_{l+1}=0,...,x_{k}=0$. 
I assume that the solution should be based on the Local Immersion theorem, which states that  "If $f:X\rightarrow  Y $ is an immersion at $x$, then there exist a local coordinates around $x$ and $y=f(x)$ such that $f(x_{1},...,x_{k})=(x_{1},...,x_{k},0,...,0)$".
I would really appreciate any pointers on how to attack this problem.

Comment: Because $Z$ is a submanifold of $X$ you know that the inclusion $i:Z\rightarrow X$ is a immersion. Now you can use the result that you have stated.

Comment: why what you said is true ..... is there a proof for this?@Tomás

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answers from Henry T. Horton at the question [Why the matrix of $dG_0$ is $I_l$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433207/why-the-matrix-of-dg-0-is-i-l) and [Augument, and injectivity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433241/augument-and-injectivity) very helpful for solving this question.

To repeat your question, which is found in Guillemin & Pallock's *Differential Topology* on Page 18, problem 2:

> Suppose that $Z$ is an $l$-dimensional submanifold of $X$ and that $z \in Z$. Show that there exists a local coordinate system {$x_1, \dots, x_k$} defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $z$ in $X$ such that $Z \cap U$ is defined by the equations $x_{l+1}=0, \dots, x_k=0$.

Here is my attempt
Consider the following diagram:

$$\begin{array}
AX & \stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow} & Z\\
\uparrow{\varphi} & & \uparrow{\psi} \\
C & \stackrel{(x_1, \dots, x_l) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_l, 0, \dots, 0)}{\longrightarrow} & C^\prime  
\end{array}
$$

Since
$$i(x_1, \dots, x_l) = (x_1, \dots, x_l,0,\dots, 0) \Rightarrow di_x(x_1, \dots, x_l) = (I_x, 0,\dots, 0).$$Clearly, $di_x$ is injective, thus the inclusion map $i: X \rightarrow Z$ is an immersion.

Then we choose parametrization $\varphi: C \rightarrow X$ around $z$, and $\psi: C^\prime \rightarrow Z$ around $i(z)$. The map $C \rightarrow C^\prime$ sends $(x_1, \dots, x_l) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_l, 0, \dots, 0)$.

The points of $X$ in a neighborhood $\varphi(C)$ around $z$ are those in $Z$ such that $x_{l+1} = \cdots x_k=0$, and this concludes the proof.

Comment: I'm providing an explicit construction of the set $U$. Let $U'$ be an open subset of $C'$ such that $U'\cap\mathbb{R}^{\ell}\times 0^{k-\ell} = C\times 0^{k-\ell}$. Define $U = \psi(U')$.