# Why the matrix of $dG_0$ is $I_l$.

Tags: differential-topology

I am reading the proof of Local Immersion Theorem in Guillemin & Pallock's *Differential Topology* on Page 15. But I got lost at the following statement:

Define a map $G: U \times \mathbb{R}^{l-k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{l}$ by
$$G(x,z) = g(x) + (0,z).$$

> The matrix of $dG_0$ is $I_l$.

Could some one explain why this is true? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Earlier on that page, it is said that since $dg_0: \Bbb R^k \longrightarrow \Bbb R^l$ is injective, we may assume that
$$dg_0 = \begin{pmatrix} I_k \\ 0_{k-l} \end{pmatrix}$$
by performing a change of basis. Hence we have that the map
$$\tilde{g}: U \times \Bbb R^{l-k} \longrightarrow \Bbb R^l,$$
$$\tilde{g}(x, z) = (g(x), 0, \dots, 0)$$
has differential
$$d\tilde{g}_0 = \begin{pmatrix} I_k & 0_{l-k} \\ 0_{l-k} & 0_{l-k} \end{pmatrix}.$$
The map
$$h: U \times \Bbb R^{l-k} \longrightarrow \Bbb R^l,$$
$$h(x,z) = (0, \dots, 0, z)$$
clearly has differential
$$dh_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 0_{k} & 0_{l-k} \\ 0_{l-k} & I_{l-k} \end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore the given map
$$G: U \times \Bbb R^{l-k} \longrightarrow \Bbb R^l,$$
$$G(x,z) = \tilde{g}(x ,z) + h(x,z)$$
has differential
$$dG_0 = d\tilde{g}_0 + dh_0 = \begin{pmatrix} I_{k} & 0_{l-k} \\ 0_{l-k} & I_{l-k} \end{pmatrix} = I_l.$$

Comment: Thank you, meow~meow~~

Comment: Hi Henry, I tried a long time but still not able to figure out why $dg_o$ is injective. Could you give me a hint..? Thanks!

Comment: Since you asked about this in a new question, I answered it there.

Comment: Got it, thanks again! May I ask how did you get into study topology/low dimensional topology? Or equivalently, what is the path? Thanks... -)

Comment: @WishingFish How is the differential of the maps h and $\bar g$ calculated?